# Checking if software is installed in SSH session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to check whether a certain package is installed on remote machine in bash script.

If I execute the following statement on the machine itself the result is 1 (installed) in file check.txt, which is correct:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed" > /home/someuser/check.txt
```

However, if I execute the same command in SSH session, the result is always 0.

Can somebody explain why and how to correct this?

Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
ADDRESS=SOMEUSER@$SOMESERVER

function run {
    ssh $ADDRESS /bin/bash $@
}

run << SSHCONNECTION

dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed" > /home/someuser/check.txt

SSHCONNECTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` character:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='\${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed" > /home/someuser/check.txt
```